# Is it Possible to Decrypt aes encryption from C# using sql server 2008?

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, cryptography, encryption-asymmetric

`

```
public class AesEncryptHelper
{
    private static readonly int _saltSize = 32;
    private static readonly string _key = "slfkey2112";
    private static string Encrypt(string plainText, string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(plainText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("plainText");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, _saltSize);            
        var saltBytes = keyDerivationFunction.Salt;
        var keyBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(32);
        var ivBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(16);

        using (var aesManaged = new AesManaged())
        using (var encryptor = aesManaged.CreateEncryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes))
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(cryptoStream))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(plainText);
            }

            var cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
            Array.Resize(ref saltBytes, saltBytes.Length + cipherTextBytes.Length);
            Array.Copy(cipherTextBytes, 0, saltBytes, _saltSize, cipherTextBytes.Length);

            return Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);
        }

    }

    public static string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        return Encrypt(plainText, _key);
    }

    private static string Decrypt(string ciphertext, string key)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ciphertext))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(key))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("key");

        var allTheBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(ciphertext);
        var saltBytes = allTheBytes.Take(_saltSize).ToArray();
        var ciphertextBytes = allTheBytes.Skip(_saltSize).Take(allTheBytes.Length - _saltSize).ToArray();

        var keyDerivationFunction = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(key, saltBytes);

        var keyBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(32);
        var ivBytes = keyDerivationFunction.GetBytes(16);
        using (var aesManaged = new AesManaged())
        using (var decryptor = aesManaged.CreateDecryptor(keyBytes, ivBytes))
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream(ciphertextBytes))
        using (var cryptoStream = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(cryptoStream))
        {
            return streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        }

    }

    public static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        return Decrypt(cipherText, _key);
    }
}
```

`
Is it possible to decrypt AES encryption in C# using an decryptor in sql server 2008? above the code i used to make an encryption in C#. i dont wanna decrypt in C# it takes long time to process , because i have a lot of data.

Comment: I find myself wondering why you want to do this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822592/how-to-get-compatibility-between-c-sharp-and-sql2k8-aes-encryption

Comment: because if i decrypt it in c sharp it takes long time, i decrypt a column with with looping and fill them (with other column) to a gridcontrol devexpress

Comment: here is the code https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3w3aUN_V-kgcHh1azRnZTJqU00/edit?usp=drive_web

Comment: You could look into having SQL do the encryption and decryption for you with a symmetric key. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/ms179331%28v=sql.105%29.aspx

Comment: Use a proper random key instead of a password. The expensive part of your code is deriving the key from the password. Moving expensive calculations from the application to the database server is a bad idea. It's still just as expensive over there, but has the additional problem that scaling application servers is typically easier than scaling databases.