# Using Sql Server 2014 to decrypt values that were encrypted in C# using AesManaged class

Tags: c#, sql-server, encryption, aes

I have some string values that have been encrypted using the AesManaged class in C# then stored on a sql database as VarBinary values.  I have access to the key (32 byte array) and initialization vector (IV)(16 byte array) that were used to perform the encryption.

What I would like to do now is decrypt the data straight from SQL-Server (2014) without having to pull the Varbinary data back into C# and then run it through the AesManaged Class again.

Is this even possible?

I have access to create keys and certificates on sql server as needed.

CLR is disabled on the Database.  I asked the DBAs, they said no.

[I found this answer and he says it's not possible, but he doesn't cite any documentation or anything](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/177066).

[I also found this answer, but it's talking about sql encrypted data being decrypted in C#.  I'm hoping to go the other way around.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2822955/3352787)

Thoughts?